# Redirect IP traffic with 'pfctl' on macOS

Tags: macos, network, pfctl

I'm working on a mac with OS 10.13.6.

I want to redirect all requests to 10.20.154.24:1111 made from my computer go to localhost:8080.

I read about pf and pfctl, but could not make this work.

I thought to run this, but it didn't work...

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 to 10.20.154.24 port 1111 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

Answer (score 2):

If your traffic is coming from your computer and since the destination isn't your computer the from can't be `127.0.0.1`. The `from IP`  is the IP address associated with the interface to use to reach `10.20.154.24`.

To make an easy test, just start by removing the part `from 127.0.0.1` in your `rdr` rule, so as to catch all traffic `tcp to 10.20.154.24 port 1111` which will include the one you want to redirect.

Next, and if this is necessary, check your outgoing interface IP address with:

```
ifconfig en0
```

(because I bet your interface is the WAN one, but adapt to your real case).